# :root having issues when compiling SCSS to CSS

Tags: css, sass

When I compile this SCSS:

```
:root {
    --card-width: 200px;
    --card-height: 300px;
    --card-transition-duration: 800ms;
    --card-transition-easing: ease;
}
```

to CSS:

```
:root {
     --card-width: 200px;
     --card-height: 300px;
     --card-transition-duration: 800ms;
     --card-transition-easing: ease;
}
```

Clearly, nothing changes. However, I run into issues.
Line 1: Rule is empty.
Lines 2, 3, 4, 5: "Expected RBRACE at line" (2, 3, 4, or 5) ", col 3".

I can't figure out what to do from here.

Comment: use an editor that shows the binary ascii values.  you maybe have some wierd control character in the mix.

Comment: do you have any recommendations? not familiar with that.

Comment: in the scss: try placing all the text on one line, no whitespace and then recompile.

Comment: recompiling it simply put the white space back and reformatted everything again. errors are the same

Comment: if this is a browser error, maybe try a different browser.

Comment: not a browser error, its a compiling error. CSS does not like the "--"

Comment: What system is showing you those errors?

Comment: css variables are supported pretty much by all modern browsers per [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/?search=css%20variables).  if nothing changes from SCSS to CSS then the compiler is fine.  Is the error preventing the page from being styled properly?

Comment: Baylum, SCSS is basically CSS with a different extension. You should not expect any differences in those custom variables